# Unir dos tablas diferentes en MySQL y mostrarlo como String

Tags: mysql

Buenas estoy queriendo unir dos tablas MySQL.

Tengo estas dos tablas equipos y players

Equipos esta constituido por:

```
  `id_equipo` int(55) NOT NULL,
  `BANDERA` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_equipo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre_jugador` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monto` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL

ALTER TABLE `equipos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_equipo`);
```

Y Players por lo siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` int(55) NOT NULL,
  `player_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_nombre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_numero` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_equipo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_liga` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_nacionalidad` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_region` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_altura` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_peso` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_edad` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_pie` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_fisico` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_posicion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `players`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

A lo que voy, estoy teniendo problemas para unir las siguientes columnas

Con id_equipo (Equipos) y player_equipo (Players)

Tengo dos jugadores registrados en la tabla Players

```
(1, '7511', 'L. MESSI', '10', '2', 'Spanish League', 'ARGENTINA', 'South America', '170', '72', '33', 'Left foot', 'C', 'RWF'),
(2, '4522', 'CRISTIANO RONALDO', '7', 'Libre', 'Serie A TIM', 'PORTUGAL', 'Europe', '187', '83', '35', 'Right foot', 'C', 'LWF')
```

Cuando un jugador no tiene equipo aparece como "Libre"
Pero si esta en un equipo le coloco la ID del equipo.

Ejemplo el resultado de arriba y abajo muestra como esta formado los equipos

```
(1, 'logo1.png', 'BOTAFOGO', 'PERSONA 1', NULL),
(2, 'logo2.png', 'U. DE CHILE', 'PERSONA 2', NULL)
```

Entonces si el jugador L.MESSI tiene la ID del equipo 2 debe aparecer el nombre del equipo U. DE CHILE

Como puedo hacer para que cuando un jugador tenga la ID de un equipo muestre el nombre del equipo y no la ID?
Espero que se pueda entender mi pregunta.
También lo ocuparía para luego ocupar en formularios es decir en un select(html) elegir un ID de equipo y colocar a ese Jugador con la ID seleccionada.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Supongo que la primera tabla es `equipos` ¿? Si es así, ¿qué hace la columna `nombre_jugador` ahí? Luego, ¿por qué la columna `player_equipo` es VARCHAR si debe relacionarse con la columna `id_equipo` que es de tipo INT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mira para el caso en el que trabajas es mejor realizar una normalización en las tablas, puesto que tienes datos repetidos en las tablas como lo son, En la tabla `equipos` tienes la columna `nombre_jugador` y en la tabla `players` tienes la columna `player_equipo` estos datos no son necesarios puesto que son atributos unicos de cada tabla, entonces si manejas las tablas de esa manera al final la tabla `equipos` sobra.

Cuando realices la normalización debería quedarte 3 tablas, pero si no quieres normalizar, debes crear una llave foránea la cual apunten a una de las 2 tablas por ejemplo: En la tabla `players` agregar una llave foránea para que apunte al `id_equipos`, esto te crea una relación donde directamente le asignas el equipo al jugador y puedes obtener los datos que necesitas en la consulta.

Normalizar es la primer recomendación que te sugiero.

Luego de eso la consulta es un poco simple porque usarías join para traer los registros que cumplen con la condición que buscas. Con lo cual, si manejas inner join te mostrara los datos que son iguales por el id o por el valor que quieres comparar, pero segun lo que entiendo es que quieres que muestre los jugadores y si tiene equipo que lo muestre y si no tambien, para ese caso puedes usar un left join o rigth join, esto pedende de donde inicies el proceso de consulta "La Tabla Donde Consultas". Pero debes tener llaves foraneas que te generen una relacion entre las 2 tablas.

El siguiente enlace te explica como es la creación de llaves foráneas. https://helisulbaransistemas.blogspot.com/2014/05/como-crear-claves-foraneas-en-mysql.html

Te recomiendo ese proceso y luego de eso te podria ayudar con la consulta como la quieres.

Espero te sirva esta aclaracion.

Comment: Genial, gracias por tu ayuda. Vo ya leer lo de claves foraneas. Tendré que re hacer las tablas.

Comment: Ah otra cosa, la columna `nombre_jugador` es el nombre de la persona que juega con ese equipo, ya que esta basado en un juego basado en PES21.

Ejemplo Juan juega con BOCA JR.
Y estoy haciendo un sistema de traspasos donde **Juan** compro un jugador y ese jugador cambio de estar **Libre** a estar en **BOCA JR.** No se si me dejo entender.

Comment: Entiendo lo que mencionas pero igual debes normalizar las tablas, crear las llaves foráneas y si quieres llevar un registro de que equipos compraron que jugadores debes crear otra tabla, siempre es recomendado simplificar las tablas y evitar la redundancia de datos entre tablas.

Comment: Si, igual voy a tener que ver videos tutoriales, porque me perdí en un par de cosas. A simple vista parece fácil muchas gracias por tu ayuda!